# When can glGenRenderbuffers() generate "0"?

Tags: opengl

I've returned to some old code that used to work to find out that it no longer does. It's supposed to render OpenGL offscreen via renderbuffers.

What's apparently happening is that this:

```
GLuint id;
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &id);
```

succeeds, but `id` is set to 0, which isn't a valid renderbuffer. Naturally, the following call to `glBindRenderbuffer()` succeeds, but then `glRenderbufferStorage()` [fails with GL_INVALID_OPERATION](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glRenderbufferStorage.xml#errors).

I check `glGetError()` after `glGenRenderbuffers()`, and the call is apparently succeeding, but I'm not getting a result out of it. Under what circumstances is it allowed to generate "0"?

For what it's worth, `glGenFramebuffers()` generates a non-zero id as expected.

(On OS X 10.10.2, Xcode 6.2, compiling against 10.9 SDK)

Comment: On the web I could find a bunch of errors related to glGenRenderBuffers(). You need to post more code, giving more context, so that anyone can help.

Comment: You're right, "how can I get it to work?" requires much more context. What I'm really asking about is the circumstances under which the function is allowed to behave this way (succeed and generate zero). No documentation for glGenRenderbuffers() that I can find lists this as a possible failure, advises checking the results for zeroes, or indicates that any prior setup is necessary.

Comment: (perhaps there is some overarching rule like "OpenGL functions have undefined behavior when there is no current context". I'll check the ordering of calls when I get home)

Comment: Not having a current context would be the most obvious explanation. But since you're saying that `glGenFramebuffers()` works, that couldn't really be it.

Comment: Apparently that is it. Sometimes the worst kind of undefined behavior is working anyway :(

Answer (score 0):

It (probably) isn't. However, if there isn't an active context, the behavior of OpenGL calls is undefined. Calls may silently fail or return garbage.

I can't find any documentation of this fact; the OpenGL documentation is (deliberately) vague about contexts, but it appears to be the case in practice.